# Single Jenkins Job for different branches

Tags: regex, git, jenkins

Can anyone let me know is there any way that I can use a single Jenkins job for different feature branches (i.e.. the job should be triggered whenever a code is pushed to any of the feature branch **and build should be triggered for that particular branch not any other branch**)

Basically a regex in which I want to avoid the master branch and some more branches with same syntax (ex. R123)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is the "multibranch pipeline": https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/

You can have a single Jenkinsfile working for all your branches or you can add exceptions for given branches for instance :

[image]

Edit :
You can totally trigger the job for feature branches only.

You want the "named branches get different properties" strategy. From there you can add an exception to suppress automatic triggering to all the branches which don't start with "feature/" :

[image]

And the job will only be applied to the feature branch having new changes.

Comment: thanks for the response, but I was expecting something different, I have edited my question in BOLD, can you please check and confirm if it can be done.

Comment: yeah it works! can we automatically trigger the build for multi branch pipeline as we do for pipeline jobs for every push.

Comment: @Gaurav You can trigger the multibranch pipeline with hooks from Bitbucket, Gitlab or Github for instance. If you want something like a Cron you can add a property to the job, like this `properties([pipelineTriggers([cron('0 * * * *')])` (but you will have to run the job once in order for the property to work).

Comment: @user_9090 Accepted answer?